# Endogenous Theories For the Origin of Earth's Water (Dry/Wet Accretion?)

Tags: water, planetary-formation

I have really two questions:

(1) what evidence is there in favour that the majority of Earth's water formed with the planet.

(2) what evidence is there that the majority of water did not form with the Earth.

Comment: Related: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/13366/12525